# elasticsearch spring data @query annotation

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to use @query annotation in elasticsearch spring data to make complex query,but when I tried the following simple query I get error

```
@Query(value="{'bool':{'must':{'field':{'name':?0}}}}")
Segment findByName(String name);
```

Stack trace

```
[ERROR] com.innvo.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exception in 
com.innvo.web.rest.RouteResource.elastic() with cause = null and
exception {}
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to
execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[6JK9sflAQK6fSCuDr-
AgkQ][segment][0]: SearchParseException[[segment][0]: from[0],size[10]:  
Parse Failure [Failed to parse source         
[{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":
"eydib29sJzp7J211c3QnOlt7J3Rlcm0nOnsnaWQnOic1MjAwJ319XX19"}]]];
nested: QueryParsingException[[segment] Failed to parse]; nested: 
JsonParseException[Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting 
either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for 
quoted) to start field name
at [Source: [B@4cc4c177; line: 1, column: 3]]; }{[6JK9sflAQK6fSCuDr-
AgkQ][segment][1]: SearchParseException[[segment][1]: from[0],size[10]: 
Parse Failure [Failed to parse source 
[{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":
"eydib29sJzp7J211c3QnOlt7J3Rlcm0nOnsnaWQnOic1MjAwJ319XX19"}]]]; nested:
QueryParsingException[[segment] Failed to parse];
nested:JsonParseException[Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was 
expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote 
(for quoted) to start field name
at [Source: [B@31702d66; line: 1, column: 3]]; }{[6JK9sflAQK6fSCuDr- 
AgkQ][segment][2]: SearchParseException[[segment][2]: from[0],size[10]:
Parse Failure [Failed to parse source    
[{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":
"eydib29sJzp7J211c3QnOlt7J3Rlcm0nOnsnaWQnOic1MjAwJ319XX19"}]]]; nested: 
QueryParsingException[[segment] Failed to parse]; nested:
JsonParseException[Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting
either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for
quoted) to start field name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `@Query` annotation you simply need to use escaped double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
@Query(value="{\"bool\":{\"must\":{\"term\":{\"name\":\"?0\"}}}}")
Segment findByName(String name);
```

Also note that I've replaced `field` by `term`(or `match` is also possible) since `field` is not a valid query.

Comment: Are you sure it's the exact same error, i.e. same message about unexpected character 39 (single quote).

Comment: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[tnDFcLa9TgWCCuRgrok6VA][segment][0]: SearchParseException[[segment][0]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJib29sIjp7Im11c3QiOnsiZmllbGQiOnsibmFtZSI6dGVzdH19fX0="}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[segment] No query registered for [field]]; }{[tnDFcLa9TgWCCuRgrok6VA][segment][1]: SearchParseException[[segment][1]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source[{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"

Comment: That's a different issue. Your query is not valid. You need to replace `field` by `term` (or `match`). See my updated answer.

Comment: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[qRBWvX1CTLSN43Xv6ChybQ][segment][0]: SearchParseException[[segment][0]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJib29sIjp7Im11c3QiOnsidGVybSI6eyJuYW1lIjp0ZXN0fX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[segment] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'test': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN

Comment: Almost there. we were missing the double quotes around the parameter `?0`, please try again

Comment: I used  Segment segment=segmentSearchRepository.findByName("test");

Comment: Can you make a query to get max value for  a field? like Segment findMaxId();

Comment: I think this should be another question, so we keep this one clean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656770/use-query-elasticsearch-spring-data-to-get-min-and-max